# Simple Query that returns millions of records for sales orders, invoices etc... is too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sapb1

I was looking for ways to improve the performance of reading a big chunk of records without indexing(it's my understanding that it could cause issues with SAP support).

My query is simple it has to return all sales order that have invoices and all independent orders and invoices as there is no clear cycle on the system.

```
SELECT    
    T5."CardCode", 
    T5."CardName",
    T4."ItemCode",
    T4."ItemName",
    T1."DocNum",
    T1."DocDate",
    T3."DocNum",
    T3."DocDate",
    T3."DocCur",
    ISNULL(T2."PriceBefDi"*T2."Quantity", 0),
    ISNULL(T2."DiscPrcnt", 0),
    ISNULL(T2."LineTotal", 0),
    ISNULL(T2."VatSum", 0),
    ISNULL(T3."DocTotal", 0),
    T2."TaxCode",
    T5."Country"
FROM 
    RDR1 T0 
FULL JOIN 
    ORDR T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry"
FULL JOIN 
    INV1 T2 ON T0."DocEntry" = T2."BaseEntry" 
            AND T0."LineNum" = T2."BaseLine" 
            AND T0."ObjType" = T2."BaseType"
FULL JOIN 
    OINV T3 ON T2."DocEntry" = T3."DocEntry"
JOIN
    OITM T4 ON T2."ItemCode" = T4."ItemCode" 
            OR T0."ItemCode" = T4."ItemCode"
JOIN 
    OCRD T5 ON T3."CardCode" = T5."CardCode" 
            OR T1."CardCode" = T5."CardCode"
JOIN 
    OSTC T6 ON T2."TaxCode" = T6."Code" 
            OR T0."TaxCode" = T6."Code"
WHERE 
    T1.[DocDate] >= [%0] 
    AND T1.[DocDate] <= [%1] 
    OR T3.[DocDate] >= [%0] 
    AND T3.[DocDate] <= [%1]
```

While this query returns the desired result, the performance is not the best when i select a large date range.

I've done a bit of research around but all the solutions I found so far were not suitable/applicable for my case as it's an SAP system so I can't go messing with standard tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To paraphrase you want 1)all orders that have invoices 2) all orders that do not have invoices 3) all invoices that do not have orders

Comment: Yes that's why i used full joins, to get everything from both tables in one query, i could do a union for each case but i am not sure if that would help performance.

Comment: I'm not sure if a UNION would be quicker either but I would give it a go.

Comment: What is the purpose of a full join to T0?  You are not reporting T0 directly.  Why and " " on column names?

Comment: I'm not too much familiar with SQL server , but why you can't use a view and refresh this view at midnight if you are not need real time data .In Oracle there is materialized view which you can define to refresh the view on demand  and creat a scheduled job or even to refresh it at midnight or any time .

Comment: @paparazzo the purpose of full joins on T0 is that T0 is the Sales Order and i need to show all sales order + all invoices + all invoices that are coming from sales order so full join is the only join that would help here. 

The " " on column names are there to facilitate converting to HANA SQL later as we often need to do that, same for case sensitivity.

Comment: @RVG90 . . . I would suggest that you simplify the query somewhat and ask a *different* question with sample data and desire results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should examine the query plan (produced by `EXPLAIN`), but in general `OR` is notorious for not using indexes.

Try splitting the query into two parts and put each side of the `OR` in each:

```
SELECT 
   ...
FROM ...
WHERE T1.[DocDate] BETWEEN [%0] AND [%1]
UNION
SELECT 
   ...
FROM ...
WHERE T3.[DocDate] BETWEEN [%0] AND [%1]
```

Note also the use use of `BETWEEN` for more clarity.

Comment: I thought of unions but is it gonna be faster if i end up showing the same amount of data anyway?

I need to show: 

Invoices with base orders
Seperate invoices
Seperate orders

so it will be 3 unions vs 1 full join that will display the same amount of data.

Comment: @RVG90 Yes, it can be a *lot* faster in my experience, but YMMV. The best and simplest thing thing is to just try it.

Comment: You are absolutely right, testing on one month (130,000+ orders and invoices) it took the full join 4 mintes and 30 seconds while it took the 3 unions 1 min and 40 seconds.

Comment: UPDATE: figured i had it as UNION when i needed UNION ALL and it now takes about 9 seconds to run, at first i thought it was because i just ran it and results where cached but when i ran the other query it took 5 mins again. 

Not sure what in UNION ALL makes it faster if anything i thought it would be the other way around as it will yield less results but i won't complain about it haha.

Comment: @RVG90 UNION ALL is always much faster than UNION because UNION removes duplicates, which requires work. However, I opted for UNION to match your original query's output. UNION ALL would produce a duplicate if *both* conditions were met.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot know the model of your base so it's not easy to say but, to speed up performance: avoid FULL JOIN. If you read some [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) you'll see it select all the row in each column you passed to it, which is a lot in your case.

My advice would be to rewrite the SQL request without FULL JOIN, only with NATURAL and INNER one.

Comment: Then i'd need to split it into 3 unions one for each case and it will end up showing the same amount of records, worth a try. 

Thx